# dom referencing only working correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a javascript function that I am calling from an image onClick event in my page.

Basically the function sets a variable which is referencing an element within the same page.

here is how the function is called (note, the html is printed using PHP, but don't think that has any effect on the html itself):

```
 echo "<img src='site/images/apps/show.gif' onClick='apps()' id='appbutton' style='#'>";
```

here is what the script references:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" name="app_frame" src="site/apps.html" width="0%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and finally, here is how it is referenced and what is done with it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function apps()
 {
 var element = document.getElementById("app_frame");
 if (element.width == '0%')
 {
    parent.document.getElementById("frame").setAttribute("width","100%");
    parent.document.getElementById("app_frame").setAttribute("width","0%");
    parent.document.getElementById("appbutton").setAttribute("src","site/images/apps/show.gif");
parent.document.getElementById("wthrbutton").style.visibility="hidden";
 }
 else
 {
    parent.document.getElementById("frame").setAttribute("width","65%");
    parent.document.getElementById("app_frame").setAttribute("width","35%");
    parent.document.getElementById("appbutton").setAttribute("src","site/images/apps/hide.gif");
    parent.document.getElementById("wthrbutton").style.visibility="visible";
 }
 }
 </script>
```

The main issue is on the first line of the function, var element = document.getelementbyid.

Firefox, Chrome and Safari all hve issues with this, and none of them seem to set the variable, which renders the rest of the script useless, as the whole thing revolves around the variable.

Anyone know any other way of setting that element as a variable that would work in these browsers?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a library like jQuery to remove broweser inconsistances?

Comment: Have you tried giving the iframe an *id* of "app_frame" as currently its just *named* "app_frame"

Comment: Hi, yes I have just tried this, however it has had no effect :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is nothing with an id of app_frame. You have set the iframe's name to app_frame. Change your iframe's code to:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" name="app_frame" id="app_frame" src="site/apps.html" width="0%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

[An article pointing out this quirk in IE](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/)

[MSDN's doc on getElementById states it returns names or id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The fact that IE "works" is a known bug. It was fixed in IE 8 best standards mode.

Comment: @Quentin According to them, this isn't a bug. It's part of their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well.

Comment: @Amaan — Since they claim it is defined in DOM level 1, and they define it differently … I'm going to continue calling it a bug.

Comment: Everyone's going to continue calling it a bug. Well, except them.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all of your replies. I have just tried adding an ID to the iframe, but doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Comment: Show us a demo page? [This simplified test case](http://jsfiddle.net/sBC5m/) works for me. Although I've changed your document.getElementById('frame').setAttribute to get the app_frame, since I don't have an element with ID frame provided in your code. What your code does is make the width of app_frame 0 if the width is 0. That doesn't make sense to me, but well, the code should work visibly anyway, because you make frame's width 100%.

Comment: Amaan, think you may have spotted my stupidity, in that I got my statement back to front :P